# Finding the sum of first two elements in a list and the second two elements and so on?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

y is a list of lists and
Total is an empty list

```
u = [ y[i][::2] for i in range(x) ]
t = [ y[i][1::2] for i in range(x) ]
for a in range(x):
    for i in range(7):
        Total.append(u[a][i]+t[a][i])
```

For example

```
y = [[1,3,6,9,2,1],[3,8,1,5,6,2]]  
u=[[3,9,1],[8,5,2]]  
t=[[1,6,2],[3,1,6]]  
Total = [[4,15,3],[11,6,8]]
```

Is there a simpler way to write this code in a more Pythonic way or is the simplest method?

Comment: I don't even understand what you mean. Can you provide some sample data and results?

Comment: Where does `x` come from?

Comment: it seems x is the length of `y[0]`

Comment: Please read how to provide a [MCVE]. In particular, your question lacks examples for the input and desired output and will probably be closed shortly if you don't update it.

Comment: there is definitely a simpler way to do that :)

Answer (score 0):

If your arrays have same length then you can use this:

Let u and t be lists

```
a=[]
for i in u:
    a.append(u[i]+t[i])
```

Comment: I don't know who upvoted this, but really take a look at it. It's *wrong*.

Answer (score 0):

Your posted syntax fails on several counts of syntax and semantics.
Simplify to this?

```
>>> [[y[i][j] + y[i][j+1]    // sum of each even index with the next one
            for j in range(0, len(y[i]), 2) ] 
        for i in range(len(y)) ] 
[[4, 15, 3], [11, 6, 8]]
```

Comment: @Prune, `range(0, len(y[i]), 2)`, palm my face, I am not aware of `range()` can set step=2 so easily.

Comment: @Gomulka: I edited my answer to handle your clarification.  That apparently came a few seconds before I posted, and I hadn't seen it when I hit the "post" button.

Comment: @Sphinx: I'm glad to be of help in this day.  As far as I know, any 3rd-generation language or later can specify the step size of its basic iteration loop.  This hearkens back to FORTRAN and Algol in the late 1950s.

Answer (score 0):

I might use a nested list comprehension.

```
y = [[1,3,6,9,2,1],[3,8,1,5,6,2]]

Total = [[i+j
          for i,j in zip(sublist[0::2], sublist[1::2])]
         for sublist in y]

assert Total == [[4,15,3],[11,6,8]]
```

- `for sublist in y` - The summation operation has to occur independently for each of the sublists in the original list.
- `sublist[0::2]` - all of the even-indexed values.
- `sublist[1::2]` - all of the odd-indexed values.
- `zip(sublist[0::2], sublist[1::2])` - A tuple with (first,second), then a tuple with (third,fourth), etc.
- `i+j for i,j in zip(...)` - Add up each of the pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Just saw you provided sample data, so update `y`. then I provide one method to produce a same result as yours.

You don't need to loop twice to get sub list for odd/even elements, then sum each of them.

Just simply loop `y[index]` with `range(half of len(y[index])`, then `sum([row[index*2], row[index*2+1]])`.

```
total = []
y = [[1,3,6,9,2,1],[3,8,1,5,6,2]]
x = len(y)

u = [ y[i][::2] for i in range(x) ]
t = [ y[i][1::2] for i in range(x) ]
for a in range(x):
    for i in range(3):
        total.append(u[a][i]+t[a][i])
#the result of your method
print('yours', total)

#below is mine:
result = list(map(lambda row: [sum([row[index], row[index+1]]) for index in range(0, len(row), 2)] , y))
print('mine',result)
print('mine', result[0]+result[1])
```

Output:

```
yours [4, 15, 3, 11, 6, 8]
mine [[4, 15, 3], [11, 6, 8]]
mine [4, 15, 3, 11, 6, 8]
[Finished in 0.163s]
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use `numpy` for this.

```
import numpy as np

y = [[1,3,6,9,2,1],[3,8,1,5,6,2]]

A = np.array(y)
res = A[:, ::2] + A[:, 1::2]

# [[ 4 15  3]
#  [11  6  8]]
```